# How to change the admin/password when using the E2E Test Utils for Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor, integration-tests

I'm trying to set up a test suite for our Gutenberg blocks plugin using the [e2e-test-utils](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/e2e-test-utils). Our environment is a multi-site WP install and I pass the WP_BASE_URL, WP_USERNAME and WP_PASSWORD as environment variables, so they are not stored anywhere in the repo.

I'm trying to make sure that the plugin I am testing on is activated using the asynchronous `activatePlugin('name-of--our-plugin')` function from the `@wordpress/e2e-test-utils` package. The problem is that this function assumes there is an existing administrator account with username: `admin` and password: `password`. This is not the case and because of our CI, I'd prefer not to have that kind of administrator account.

Is there a way to pass to the script administrator's credentials as environment variables just like I do it with the user? The admin user appears to be hardcoded in the [config.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/e2e-test-utils/src/shared/config.js) file.